# How do I receive a variable from python flask to JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, python, flask

I've seen how to make a post request from JavaScript to get data from the server, but how would I do this flipped. I want to trigger a function in the flask server that will then dynamically update the variable on the JavaScript side to display. Is there a way of doing this in a efficient manner that does not involve a periodic iteration. I'm using an api and I only want to the api to be called once to update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three basic options for you:

1. **Polling** - With this method, you would periodically send a request to the server (maybe every 5 seconds for example) and ask for an update. The upside is that it is easy to implement. The downside is that many requests will be unnecessary. It sounds like this isn't a great option for you.
2. **Long Polling** - This method means you would open a request up with the server and leave the request open for a long period of time. When the server gets new information it will send a response and close the request - after which the client will immediately open up a new "long poll" request. This eliminates some of the unnecessary requests with regular polling, but it is a bit of a hack as HTTP was meant for a reasonably short request response cycle. Some PaaS providers only allow a 30 second window for this to occur for example.
3. **Web Sockets** - This is somewhat harder to setup, but ultimately is the best solution for real time server to client (and vice versa) communication. A socket connection is opened between the server and client and data is passed back and forth whenever either party would like to do so. Javascript has full web socket support now and Flask has some extensions that can help you get this working. There are even great third party managed solutions like Pusher.com that can give you a working concept very quickly.

Comment: I second that websockets recommendation